# how to have content disappear/hidden behind transparent header while scrolling

Tags: html, css

I created a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/claireC/8SUmn/ with a fixed header that is transparent.

When I scroll, you're able to see the text scrolling up behind it. How can I have the text disappear or hidden behind the transparent div on scroll.

edit: Forgot to mention that the background is an image.

Note: I am a beginner in coding. This is me playing around with code and trying to figure things out.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="container">

<header>
    <ul>
        <li>list one</li>
        <li>list3   </li>
        <li>list2</li>
    </ul>
</header>

<div class="text">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce placerat sapien eget ligula egestas, quis aliquam velit varius. Phasellus mollis mollis sem quis porttitor. Pellentesque scelerisque mauris et magna tincidunt, vel pharetra enim pharetra. Duis a lobortis purus. Sed dignissim fermentum nibh convallis eleifend. In quis interdum arcu. Proin interdum, lorem et luctus laoreet, felis purus pharetra turpis, eu egestas justo ligula in lectus. Morbi vitae libero vel velit posuere luctus at eu diam. Duis tincidunt lectus ut lobortis euismod. Vivamus ultrices tristique sapien eget posuere.

    </p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
    header{
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .text{
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 150px;
    }

    p{
        font-size: 150px;
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of having a transparent header if you want the content that scrolls underneath to be hidden? Setting the header to white will make it look the same, but the content behind will be hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/8SUmn/1/

Comment: Sorry. I had a picture for a background image, but I'm not sure how to get it in js fiddle

Comment: Ah, well its possible, but you would have to set the height of your header (can't be dynamic)

Comment: Here's an example with a background image http://jsfiddle.net/claireC/8SUmn/

Comment: Either you have a picture or just an color, my example should work as you wish, did you test it ?

Comment: You do not need to set height to the header, flexbox is great for this type of stuff - check out my answer, very simple solution.

Comment: @KevinJantzer why would you say, "it can't be dynamic"? Of course it can.

Comment: @MrRobboto provide an example then

Comment: @KevinJantzer I did. stackoverflow.com/a/58713553/11279581

Answer (score 9):

If you are ok with setting the header height, you can use `position:absolute` and `overflow:auto` to get the result

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8SUmn/3/)

Comment: "half the screen"? It fills the entire scrollable area.

Comment: What part of "How can I have the text disappear or hidden behind the transparent div on scroll." is my example not doing?

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but not sure how it works. So the text is overflowing from the top?

What is wrong with setting the header height?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with setting the header height, but some people may not want to (dynamic based how much is in the header).

Comment: Why was position absolute used? Would I not be able to achieve this effect using position relative?

Comment: I used `absolute` so that the bottom scrolling section would take up all the screen but also scale when the page was resized

Comment: I had to set what would be text to `.text { max-height: calc( 100% - 120px );  }` to fix it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, CSS only:

- make a container div with your background
- have the **header** transparant and `height` set to `10vh`
- have the **body** `height` set to `90vh` and `overflow` to `auto`

Sorry, it's React/MaterialUI, but you'll get the gist:

```
const classes = theme => ({
  container: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif',
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    minHeight: '100%',
    backgroundImage: 'url(/cargo-background.jpg)',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
  }
})

<div className={classes.container}>
    <div style={{height: '12vh'}}>
      <AppBar/>
    </div>
    <div style={{height: '88vh', overflow: 'auto'}}>
      <Routes/>
    </div>
</div>
```

More on vh (viewport units): 
https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your header is going to be like a sticky menu, that shows the background image underneath - I think it will be a lot easier to achieve without the text actually behind your header/menu. Instead you're better off doing a fixed layout IMO, here's an example:

There is a full screen container to start the fixed layout, and inside a header, and content section. You can use flexbox here to make the content section fill the space but not overflow, while the header height is based on the header contents (so no, you don't have to set height on the header as people are saying).

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background: ghostwhite;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

header.menu {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

section.text {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>list one</li>
      <li>list3 </li>
      <li>list2</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <section class="text">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce placerat sapien eget ligula egestas, quis aliquam velit varius. Phasellus mollis mollis sem quis porttitor. Pellentesque scelerisque mauris et magna tincidunt, vel pharetra enim pharetra.
      Duis a lobortis purus. Sed dignissim fermentum nibh convallis eleifend. In quis interdum arcu. Proin interdum, lorem et luctus laoreet, felis purus pharetra turpis, eu egestas justo ligula in lectus. Morbi vitae libero vel velit posuere luctus at
      eu diam. Duis tincidunt lectus ut lobortis euismod. Vivamus ultrices tristique sapien eget posuere. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce placerat sapien eget ligula egestas, quis aliquam velit varius. Phasellus mollis mollis
      sem quis porttitor. Pellentesque scelerisque mauris et magna tincidunt, vel pharetra enim pharetra. Duis a lobortis purus. Sed dignissim fermentum nibh convallis eleifend. In quis interdum arcu. Proin interdum, lorem et luctus laoreet, felis purus
      pharetra turpis, eu egestas justo ligula in lectus. Morbi vitae libero vel velit posuere luctus at eu diam. Duis tincidunt lectus ut lobortis euismod. Vivamus ultrices tristique sapien eget posuere.

    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```